# Ammo.js repeated matrix row access changes previous references

Tags: javascript, reference, ammo.js

I'm encountering behavior I don't understand using ammo.js (the Emscripten port of Bullet to JavaScript). I store each of the three rows of a **btMatrix3x3** off in separate variables, but when I log the variables to the console, they all contain the values of the last row I accessed.
For example, this code:

```
let transform = Ammo.btTransform();
transform.setIdentity();
const basis = transform.getBasis();
const row0 = basis.getRow(0);
const row1 = basis.getRow(1);
const row2 = basis.getRow(2);

console.log(row0.x() + "," + row0.y() + "," + row0.z());
console.log(row1.x() + "," + row1.y() + "," + row1.z());
console.log(row2.x() + "," + row2.y() + "," + row2.z());
```

prints 0,0,1 three times. However, this code:

```
const row0 = basis.getRow(0);
console.log(row0.x() + "," + row0.y() + "," + row0.z());
const row1 = basis.getRow(1);
console.log(row1.x() + "," + row1.y() + "," + row1.z());
const row2 = basis.getRow(2);
console.log(row2.x() + "," + row2.y() + "," + row2.z());
```

successfully prints 1,0,0\n0,1,0\n0,0,1.

My best guess is **getRow** is returning some reference to something internal to **btMatrix3x3**, and so my row variables all end up pointing to the same place, but I don't really know what's going on.

Can someone please explain what's happening so I can avoid being bitten by this in the future? Also, is there a way to do what I want and store off the three rows separately instead of processing them one at a time?